# Run Junit test class inside one-jar with junit outside the jar

Tags: java, command-line, jar, junit, executable-jar

So I have packed my classes and their dependancies (apache commons cli) inside a jar file using [one-jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) (which was easy enough to do, see section [Command-Line Approach](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=getting-started&file=quickstart)). Now I am curious if I can run the java test class inside the jar using a Junit jar outside the class. So the path to the test class inside `sw.jar` is :

```
sw.jar\main\sw.jar\uoa\di\ys11\hw2\TestSmithWaterman.class
```

(the `main\` is a one-jar thing). I have tried variations of :

```
java -jar -cp lib/junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore  uoa.di.ys11.hw2.TestSmithWaterman
```

with no luck - so what would the command line be ? Or do I need to modify the one-jar manifest somehow ?

EDIT : the `/boot-manifest.mf`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot
One-Jar-Main-Class: uoa.di.ys11.hw2.Hw2
```

while the `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_09 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot
One-Jar-Main-Class: uoa.di.ys11.hw2.Hw2
```

Comment: Good.. but can you edit it to *add a question?*

Comment: @AndrewThompson:ok now added in the body (I thought the title would be enough, sorry)

Comment: Stating "this is what I am trying to achieve" or "..want to do" is not actually a question.  Asking a *specific* (which you have now done) makes the post fit better in a Q&A site and helps hone the answers.  You've now asked some questions, good.  Please make sure to add a question in future (without any prompt).

Comment: Do you have any test methods in the class? Better to post the code.

Comment: @RomanC: the code for the TestSmithWaterman class is here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/ykthr7v8rw7r0a8/TestSmithWaterman.java. The jar is here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/n0mbf6owbosr2y2/sw.jar

Comment: You need to include the *entire* classpath if you use `-cp`. And you don't use `-jar` if you're not running a jar.

Comment: @Dave : if you could make this work I'd appreciate it :D

Comment: When using the `-jar` option, the `-cp` option is ignored.  I don't know if this was the case in 2013, but it is now: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following command line to test

```
java -cp lib/junit.jar;sw.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore  uoa.di.ys11.hw2.TestSmithWaterman
```

**EDIT:**

this should be work with normal jars, but the jar is created by the one-jar

> One-JAR lets you package a Java application together with its
>   dependency Jars into a single executable Jar file.

After that it's not possible for junit, as I mention junit-4.4 in my case to load such classes for test.

Comment: `java -cp lib/junit.jar;sw.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore uoa.di.ys11.hw2.TestSmithWaterman` results in `JUnit version 4.10
Could not find class: uoa.di.ys11.hw2.TestSmithWaterman 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing` etc

Comment: sw.jar should be in the current folder or you should specify the full path to the jar

Comment: it is in the current folder (by lib/)

Comment: is lib in the current folder and sw.jar in the lib? If so, then use lib/sw.jar

Comment: the class SelfDescribing is in the another jar should be added to the classpath (-cp)

Comment: which brings us to the meat of the problem : if I do add it I get :`JUnit version 4.10
Could not find class: uoa.di.ys11.hw2.TestSmithWaterman

Time: 0

OK (0 tests)`

Comment: The problem lies in the structure of the jar - `java -cp lib/junit.jar;sw.jar;lib/org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar;lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar;bin/ org.junit.runner.JUnitCore uoa.di.ys11.hw2.TestSmithWaterman` works fine (bin/ is the usual Eclipse compile folder)

Comment: If your TestSmithWaterman is another sw.jar that is in sw.jar as you written in the some weird path `sw.jar\main\sw.jar\uoa\di\ys11\hw2\TestSmithWaterman.class` then junit will not be able to load such class. Use simple jar created by jar command.

Comment: so see ? you should read more carefully - accepted but still I believe it is possible - if someone comes up with a way - the dropbox links I posted in comments are valid (so if anyone wants to play with the jar...)

Comment: Sure, it's great especially with the maven plugin, many people have troubles with creating executable jars with eclipse, even testers.